# Change group id when acting in directory

Tags: linux, permissions, user-groups

I have a directory `shared` where people part of group `common` have `rwx` permission inside.
And user `john`

```
$> id john
uid=1000(john)gid=1000(john)groups=1000(john),10(common)
```

It would be nice if user `john` which is part of group `common` and his own group could change automatically his group (implicitly with command `newgrp`) only if he's acting inside the directory `shared`.

Like this:

```
john $> pwd
/home/john
john $> id
uid=1000(john)gid=1000(john)groups=1000(john),10(common)   # gid is john

john $> ls -ld /shared
rwxrwx--- root common ... /shared/                         # here shared is part group common

john $> cd /shared
john $> id
uid=1000(john)gid=10(common)groups=1000(john),10(common)   # gid is common

john $> cd ~
john $> id
uid=1000(john)gid=1000(john)groups=1000(john),10(common)   # gid is john
```

Like this, users could acts on files as if they were their own.>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest doing a chmod on the directory to add the SGID bit.

```
 chmod g+s directory
```

What happens is that any files created get the group assigned the group of the directory automagically.